# What platforms offer SystemRandom?

Tags: python, random, cryptography, portability, prng

Python's `random.SystemRandom` provides cryptographic-quality pseudorandom numbers.  What platforms is it supported on?  Most importantly, are there any platforms that it is not supported on, and if so, which ones?  Can anyone provide any information about how portable it is?

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

> The random module also provides the `SystemRandom` class which uses the system function  `os.urandom()` to generate random numbers from sources provided by the operating system.

From http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom

> This function returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation. On a UNIX-like system this will query `/dev/urandom`, and on Windows it will use `CryptGenRandom`. If a randomness source is not found, `NotImplementedError` will be raised.

Comment: And on VMS, it uses OpenSSL's RAND_pseudo_bytes, as you can see by reading [the source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release32-maint/Modules/posixmodule.c?view=markup).

Comment: @tylerl, yeah, I already read the docs, and I already knew it is supported on Windows and on Unix platforms that have /dev/urandom.  But again, I'm most interested in knowing which platforms it is *not* supported on, as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I could just sense you are using VMS

Comment: @Nemo: And what does OpenSSL's RAND_psuedo_bytes use on VMS?

Comment: @GregS:  Don't tell me it uses Python's os.urandom !?!?

Comment: @Nemo: I don't know, I'm asking you!

Comment: From what I understand, RAND_psuedo_bytes is similar to /dev/urandom on linux, as it uses an acquired entropy pool for true randomness, but re-uses entropy to avoid blocking.