# Generate 6 digits pin code using python

Tags: python, cryptography

I want to build python algorithm that generates 6 digits pin code. I had many ideas like : based on time, on id .... etc, but non sounded secure once the algorithm is exposed. Now I am trying to generate that using `random.randint(a, b)`, however I want to know how it really works and python documentation don't provide much about it. So can you please provide more about this or any other suggestions to generate 6 digits pin code.

Comment: Do you mean how it randomly picks the numbers or how to use the function?

Comment: You can find out yourself how it works, by looking into the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/random.py#L214-L218).

Answer (score 5):

This method will return you by default a 6 number sized string and if you pass in a value as many numbers as you passed in.

```
import string
import random

def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
```

> print(id_generator())
>
> 123123
>
> print(id_generator(10))
>
> 1234512345

Comment: I tried to call the functions many times, it gives a number for some and "None" on the other

Comment: How did you call it? It's working with me.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to securely implement this is to use the operating system's random number generator(random.SystemRandom() or os.urandom(n)) to generate your digits. The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html) has a nice big warning against using the default generator.

The one caveat is that SystemRandom() apparently doesn't work on all systems, though from what I can tell [no one's quite sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219254/what-platforms-offer-systemrandom) what systems don't support it.

other than that, random.SystemRandom().randint() should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a very simple solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from random import choice
from string import digits

code = list()
for i in range(6):
    code.append(choice(digits))

print ''.join(code)
```

Output something like:

```
455799
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the direct approach, although this is more like Fortran than Python. You can also repurpose this as a key generator.

```
    import random
    def pin_code(n)
        pin = []
        for i in range(n):
            pin.append(random.randint(0,9))
        print(*pin, sep='')
```

Comment: This isn't really helping, as OP question is mainly about security concerns of using `random.randint`.